# Jacobson Radical of semisimple module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, semi-simple-rings

Suppose that $M$ is a semisimple module. I want to show that $J(M)=0$

If $N$ is a simple submodule of $M$, then $M=N \oplus N'$ and $M/N'$ is isomorphic to $N$ and so is simple. Then $N'$ must be maximal, so it contains $J(M)$. Then $J(M)\cap N=(0)$.

Since $M$ is semisimple, so it is a direct sum of simple modules, each of which intersects $J(M)$ in (0).

Why $J(M)\cap M=(0)?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, since $M$ is semisimple we have

$$
M = \bigoplus_{i \in I}S_i
$$

with each $S_i$ simple. Pick $x \in M \cap J(M)$ and write

$$
x = s_1 + \cdots + s_n
$$

with $s_i \in S_{j_i}$ and $j_1, \dots, j_n \in I$. Since $S_{j_i}$ is simple for each $i$, we have that $\bigoplus_{I \setminus \{j_i\}}S_i$ is maximal and thus contains $J(M)$. However, since $x \in J(M)$, in particular this would show that

$$
s_i = x-(s_1+\dots+\widehat{s_i}+\dots+s_n) \in \bigoplus_{I \setminus \{j_i\}}S_i
$$

which implies $s_i = 0$, and so $x = 0$.

Comment: Actually my question is that why $J(M)$ intersection with a direct sum, is the direct sum of intersections?

Comment: I'll add a proof.

Comment: @S_Alex okay, so, I don't know if the former equality is actually true, but I think I've managed to prove the fact via your observations nonetheless.